# Python.h: No such file or directory with python36-devel installed

Tags: python, gcc, gcc-warning, pkg-config

I have searched tones of threads for this.

when i am installing **python-ldap** i get:

```
  In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:3:0:
  Modules/common.h:9:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
                      ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

i have Python 3.6 and i already have installed **python36-devel** and **openldap-devel**

as far as i can see:

```
[xfft@hostname Scripts]$ pkg-config --cflags python
-I/usr/include/python2.7
[xfft@hostname Scripts]$ pkg-config --libs python
-lpython2.7
```

in **/usr/include/** i have:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Apr 28 14:35 python2.7
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Apr 28 14:51 python3.6m
```

and in **python3.6m** there is **Python.h**

But how to point **pkg-config --cflags python** and **pkg-config --libs python** to this directory?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody ad similar issue, here is what fixed the issue:

I have checked **/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/** and there was no **pkgconfig** directory inside.

What i was missing was **rh-python36-python-devel**. So this fixed the issue:

```
yum install rh-python36-python-devel
```